# How to reset all objects specific value in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have the following `useState`:

```
  const [markedDates, setMarkedDates] = useState({
   "2022-04-05": {
     "selected": false,
   },
   "2022-04-08": {
     "selected": false,
   }
  });
```

**Goal**

My goal is to toggle the following to `true` or `false`.

[image]

But, only **one** object can be set as `true`, and this is where I am struggling to think of a correct method using React to achieve such logic.

As an example, I want to set `2022-04-05.selected` to `true`:

```
  const [markedDates, setMarkedDates] = useState({
   "2022-04-05": {
     "selected": true, ######### SET AS TRUE #########
   },
   "2022-04-08": {
     "selected": false,
   }
  });
```

Now I want to set `2022-04-08.selected` as `true`:

```
  const [markedDates, setMarkedDates] = useState({
   "2022-04-05": {
     "selected": false, ######### SET BACK TO FALSE #########
   },
   "2022-04-08": {
     "selected": true, ######### SET TO TRUE #########
   }
  });
```

**Question**

What would be the correct method to achieve such logic?

**What I have tried**

I came up with the following solution, but I am not sure if this is the correct way of re-setting all objects properties (`selected = false`) in react.

```
  const reset = () => {
    let resetMarkedDates = markedDates;
    for (const date in resetMarkedDates) {
      resetMarkedDates[date].selected = false;
    }
    setMarkedDates(resetMarkedDates);
  };

  const onDayPress = (day) => {
    reset();
    setMarkedDates((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      [day]: { selected: true },
    }));
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a global variable instead of putting it directly in the `useState` parameter to be able to reset the initial state each time `onDayPress` is called. Note that, in your logic, since the previous state is the initial one, there's no need to pass a function to `setState` parameter if you aim to reset all the `selected` except one.

```js
const initialState = {
  "2022-04-05": {
     "selected": false,
   },
   "2022-04-08": {
     "selected": false,
   }
}

const [markedDates, setMarkedDates] = useState(initialState);

const onDayPress = (day) => {
    setMarkedDates({
       ...initialState,
       [day]: { selected: true } 
      });
};
```

Comment: That's a quick, efficient and easy to read alternative method, thank you @testing_22